# Stripe is not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, fetch-api

I had created a project in which I had used stripe api and it was working perfectly fine, I'm using the same api keys in my next project but it keeps giving me errors, I resolved a few but still nothing is happening when I click the button "Get my plan".

This is my app.js:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path') 
const app = express();


const env = require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
var Publishable_Key = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
var Secret_Key = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
const stripe = require('stripe')(Secret_Key) 

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render('home.ejs');
   });
   app.get('/payment/success', async (req, res) => {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
   
  res.render('success',{name:customer.name})
  });
  app.get("/payment/discount",(req,res)=>{
    res.render('cancel',{publishablekey:Publishable_Key})
  })

  const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
  };
  app.post('/payment', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res)=>{ 
    const { product } = req.body;
    const YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://localhost:5000";
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            line_items: [
                {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: "usd",
                        product_data: {
                            name: product.name
                        },
                        unit_amount: product.amount * 100,
                    },
                    quantity: product.quantity,
                },
            ],
            
            mode: "payment",
            success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/payment/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
            cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/payment/discount`,
        });
    
        res.json({ id: session.id });
    })) 

    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        // your error code
        console.log(err);
     })
 app.get('/offer', (req, res) => {
    res.render('offer',{publishablekey:Publishable_Key})
  });
```

This is my offer.ejs

```
                   <span>Your plan is ready</span>
                           <form id="payment-form2">
                                 <a > <button id="submit2">Get my plan</button></a>
                           </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
   var publishableKey = '<%=publishablekey%>'
    var stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);
    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const card = elements.create('card');
    const form2 = document.getElementById('payment-form2');
    let submitted = false;
    
    form2.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const {error: backendError, clientSecret} = await fetch("/payment", {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "product": {
                "name": "Your Personalised Plan", 
                "amount": 100,
                "quantity": 1
            }})
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
       
    });
  </script>
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\app.js:52:43
    at C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\app.js:39:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)    
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at serveStatic (C:\Users\singh\Documents\wizdom-node\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
```

Please can anyone help me in this, it's important!!

Comment: If you add `console.log(req.body);` above `const { product } = req.body;` do you get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining that name is not defined, which is coming from the POST request. Is the POST request body in a format `app.js` is expecting it in?